# Flutter - Using Firebase Auth GoogleSignIn with the Gmail API

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a Flutter app with 2 screens. The first is a sign-in screen with a single button that uses Firebase Authentication as well as the Flutter GoogleSignIn package to sign users in with their Google accounts. Once the user successfully signs in, they're automatically routed to the second screen by Firebase Auth, on which I will use the Gmail API to actually write the functionality of the app.

I have working code to use GoogleSignIn with Firebase Auth to sign the user in. This code is located in a separate class I named `auth_service.dart`. I call the `signInWithGoogle()` function when the "Sign In" button is tapped on the first screen.

```
class AuthService {
  signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: <String>[GmailApi.gmailReadonlyScope],
    );

    final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: gAuth.idToken,
    );

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
}
```

This code works. From my research, I found that in order to use GoogleApis, I need to create an HTTP client with the `extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth` package like so:

```
final httpClient = (await googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;
GmailApi gmailApi = GmailApi(httpClient);
```

The issue is with figuring out where to put these 2 lines of code. The first line relies on the `googleSignIn` variable, which is only available in the `AuthService` class shown above. However, putting these 2 lines inside the `AuthService` class would make the `gmailApi` variable and corresponding HTTP client unavailable to anything outside of this file, meaning I wouldn't be able to call the Gmail API from the second screen. And since routing is handled automatically by Firebase Authentication, I'm not sure if I could even pass in the HTTP client to the next screen as a parameter. I tried making a `globals.dart` file and setting the HTTP client as a global variable. While this technically works, the HTTP client variable becomes null every time the app is closed and re-opened, forcing the user to go through the sign in flow again.

How can I keep the user signed in across app refreshes while also having access to the Gmail API HTTP client on the second screen?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example Example of preserving state.
https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/example Usage example.